# Attempted import error: 'formatDate' is not exported from 'src/utils'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a utils file in React where it uses a library, but the exported function is not visible to other files with the following compilation error:

`Attempted import error: 'formatDate' is not exported from 'src/utils'.`

As soon as I remove the library, the code compiles and works greatly. Also, if I use the library code directly from my component the code compiles and works.

I have searched a lot to know what the problem is with exporting a function that is using a library but found nothing relevant.

```
import moment from 'moment';

exports.formatDate = (format, date) => {
  return moment(date).format(format);
}
```

Comment: Try exporting it using the ES6 syntax? Like `export const formatDate...` or `export function formatDate...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
exports.formatDate = (format, date)
```

To

```
export const formatDate = (format, date) => {
```

Comment: works greatly, thanks. The `function` however is necessary => `export const formatDate = function(format, date)`

Comment: Ops My bad, Yes, the arrow is needed

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between `exports`  and `export` .

export actually sends out an object which we can consume in our appropriate files.

so if you do `export { formatDate }`;

Then you can use `import { formatDate } from './utils`;

we won't be using module exports (`exports`) along with `import`, and it has to be paired with the `require` syntax, that you can find in earlier es versions.

considering your file is util,

```
const formatDate = (format, date) => moment(date).format(format);
export {
     formatDate,
     myOtherUtil,
};
```

you can follow this structure.